# Should I Convert to Navigation Component/Editor in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, deprecated

My project is extremely large, 5+ years in the making. I just recently updated from API 21 to API 30 and am handling deprecation warnings. I get the error:

**Screenshot of deprecation warning**
[image]

`"Consider using other common navigation patterns instead"`, which the link leads to the Navigation Components page.

After some research, it seems like there is no other 'quick' solution other than Navigation Component. It also seems like converting will take possibly months to rewrite the entire app. Should I just keep using it?:

```
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD)
```

or is deprecation going to be a huge issue for the users?

Comment: I would think this just limits what version of the API you can use, which will eventually diminish your user base.

Comment: @user3727648 My minSDK is 24, but this was deprecated in 21. I just don't want all of my code to eventually be deprecated.